# Using mapping/display tools in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

Does ModelBuilder have anything equivalent to the arcpy.mapping module, specifically zoomToSelectedFeatures, ExportToPDF, and TextElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you could call such code in the model through the model only tool [Calculate Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm).